# Flicker of login page on Authentication - useAuthenticator - React - Amplify Auth

Tags: javascript, aws-amplify

Below is code:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator( context => [context.authStatus]);
  
  return (
    <>
    { authStatus === 'authenticated' ? children : <Navigate to ="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />}
    </>
  )
}
```

When authenticated user goes to page or refreshes, page will flicker the /login page and then children will render.

I assume it is while promise is resolving, but I do not know what to do to add spinner or pending while promise resolves...

Thank you for assistance...

Answer (score 0):

According to https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/headless#authentication-check, `authStatus` can be either `authenticated`, `unauthenticated`, or `configuring`.

Your application is likely flickering because you do not handle `configuring` case. I would expand the conditional like so:

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthenticator, Loader } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';

export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator( context => [context.authStatus]);

  if (authStatus === 'authenticated') {
    return <>{children}</>;
  } else if (authStatus === 'unauthenticated') {
    return <Navigate to ="/login" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  } else {
    return <Loader />; // or your own spinner
  }
}
```

Comment: Thank you William, it seems I may have a few other situations state/loading wise - let me work with these a bit and I'll get back to you...