# useAuthenticator authStatus stuck on `configuring`, Amplify react-ui

Tags: reactjs, aws-amplify, authenticator

I am trying to fetch the auth status as in the [route protection example](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/guides/auth-protected), but seemed to always be redirected. Upon further debugging, I noticed that the `route` const was always set to `idle`, and so I tried to use `authStatus` instead (seemingly a better fit for this purpose anyway), eg.

```
  const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.authStatus]);
```

Unfortunately, this also seems to always be set to `configuring`, which based on the [documentation](https://ui.docs.amplify.aws/react/connected-components/authenticator/advanced#authentication-check), this shouldn't be happening, and this state should only be reserved for first load.

I found this [thread](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/74261254/authstatus-is-not-changing-from-configuring-state-using-amplify-ui-react), but have been unable to implement the solution, as it is hiding all my login pages (below is an example of how I was trying it)

hideAuth.css

```
[data-amplify-authenticator] {
display:none;
}
```

RequireAuth.js

```
import { useLocation, Navigate } from 'react-router-dom';
import { useAuthenticator } from '@aws-amplify/ui-react';
import '../App.css';
import '../hideAuth.css';

export function RequireAuth({ children }) {
  const location = useLocation();
  const { authStatus } = useAuthenticator((context) => [context.authStatus]);
  if (authStatus !== 'authenticated') {
    return <Navigate to="/unauthenticated" state={{ from: location }} replace />;
  }
  return children;
}
```

App.js

```
.
.
.
function MyRoutes() {
  return (
    <BrowserRouter>
      <Routes>        
        <Route exact path="/" element={<Home />} />
        <Route path="/login" element={<Login />} />
        <Route
          path="/dashboard" 
          element={
            <Authentication>     // I did not normally have this Authentication wrapper
              <RequireAuth>
                <Dashboard />
              </RequireAuth>
            </Authentication>    // It was added as suggested in the linked thread
          }
        />
        <Route path="*" element={<ErrorPage />} />
        <Route path="/unauthenticated" element={<Unauthenticated />} />
      </Routes>
    </BrowserRouter>
  );
}

function App() {
  return (
    <Authenticator.Provider>
      <MyRoutes />
    </Authenticator.Provider>
  );
}

export default App;
```

The answer in the thread above does suggest that there has been a solution using `npm i @aws-amplify/react-ui@next`, but trying this hasnt changed any behaviour I have been seeing - am I doing something wrong?